# ExactTarget API SOAP - Timestamp

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are sending triggered emails to exacttarget via the SOAP API.

There is a time difference of 8 hours between the time we send the mail and the time that the report in ET says the email was sent.

Our timezone settings in ET is correct (GMT+2)

We have logged this with ET but have had no success.

We are testing with Postman. Is there a setting we can add to add in a timestamp?

Comment: Do you mean that the email is not actually sent out for 8 hours? Or that it sends out but takes 8 hours for reports and logs to say the email was sent? Or is it sent and reported immediately, but the time it shows is 8 hrs from your current time?

Comment: It sends out at the correct time, say 2pm (gmt+2) but when I look at the report in ET, The send time that it sent 8 hours ahead.

Comment: Your last comment might be wrong or unprecise: CST is behind GMT+2. When the send time in GMT+2 is 14:00 alias 2PM the send time of the reports should be 6AM. Different Case: keep this in mind: When the send time on GMT+2 would be 30th January 6AM the report will show you 29th of January 10PM.

Comment: You are 100% correct. That is exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your company is in the timezone gmt+2 but the Marketing Cloud Servers are running on CST (Central Standard Time).

All timestamps inside the sendlog or data_views of marketing cloud are based on CST. Therefore the is a -8h (or different when daylight savings inside your timezone) difference.

Ampscript has functions for this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SystemDateToLocalDate.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/LocalDateToSystemDate.htm

Comment: As a note, setting the TZ inside of Admin for your instance does not affect the Server values, which is why the AMPScript functions were created. You can also manipulate these values via SQL queries for reporting needs.